# StackOverFlow Error in using change listener in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have a textfield, its input data should be 16 digits and after 4th,8th,12th digit should typed space,I wrote this code and when I add the second inner condition if , the program have stack over flow error,what should I do?what is the problem?please help.
this is my code, I use change listener:

```
  cardNumberField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1){    
            if (t1.length() > 0) {
                String s = null;
                s = t1.substring(t1.length() - 1,t1.length());
                if (!s.matches("\\d") || t1.length() > 19) {
                    cardNumberField.setText(t);
                }
                if(t1.length() == 4 || t1.length() == 9 || t1.length() == 14){
                    cardNumberField.setText(t1 + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: as a general rule, a listener _must not_ change the state of the notifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have three characters ("123") in the text field and type a fourth character which is a digit, e.g. "4". This, of course, invokes your listener.

The first condition is false (because the last character is a digit, and the length is less than 16). 
The second condition is true because `t1.length()==4`. So you now invoke `setText("1234 ")`.
This changes the text, so it invokes your listener again. This time the first condition matches (because the last character is not a digit). So now you invoke `setText("1234")`.

This changes the text, so it invokes your listener.
The first condition is false (because the last character is a digit, and the length is less than 16). 
The second condition is true because `t1.length()==4`. So you now invoke `setText("1234 ")`.
This changes the text, so it invokes your listener again. This time the first condition matches (because the last character is not a digit). So now you invoke `setText("1234")`.

And so on. So you basically have infinite recursion, and at some point (pretty quickly) the stack can't hold all the method calls.

To fix it, fix your logic. It might be better to prevent the user from entering invalid text, rather than listening for it and trying to remedy it after the fact. You may want to look at [this](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/restricting-input-on-a-textfield/).